# React Native TextInput not responsive

Tags: android, react-native

hello i am in the process of making my app resonsive i came across dimensions and find it pretty easy to use i don't really know if it is recommended as i am not that familiar with it yet. now the problem in my android emulator everything looks fine as it should the textbox adjusts to the size and the text is also in the middle of the textbox but on my real android device the text is shifted pretty far up does anyone know how i can fix this?

My Code:

```
//On the top to get the Dimensions

let height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
let width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

My TextInput:

```
      <TextInput
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      style={styles.inputStyle}
      placeholder="Name"
      value={clientName}
      onChangeText={setClientName}
    />
```

And my responsive input style:

```
inputStyle: {
width: width * 0.7,
height: height* 0.06,
fontSize: height * 0.03,
textAlign: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#D6D6D6',
color: '#000',
borderRadius: 10,
```

},

here a screenshot from my real device
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding padding: 0 in style. It will remove blank space around text.

```
inputStyle: {
width: width * 0.7,
height: height* 0.06,
fontSize: height * 0.03,
textAlign: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#D6D6D6',
color: '#000',
borderRadius: 10,
padding: 0,
},
```